# Self-made list in c++

Tags: c++, list

```
list.h

class Link {
public:
    string value;
    Link(const string& v, Link* p = 0, Link * s = 0):
        value(v), prev(p), succ(s) {}
    Link* insert(Link* n);              // insert n before this object
    Link* add(Link* n);                 // insert n after this object
    Link* erase();                      // remove this object from list
    Link* find(const string& s);        // find s in list
    Link* const find(const string& s) const;                       
    Link* advance(int n) ;                // get the nth successor 

    Link* next() const { return succ; }
    Link* previous() const { return prev; }

private:
    Link* prev;
    Link* succ;
};
```

Can you tell me why we need two versions of `find()`

```
Link* find(const string& s);        // find s in list
Link* const find(const string& s) const;
```

in this self-made double-linked list and what should the main difference be between these two versions?

Comment: There is a `const` and `non-const` version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you want a `const` and a non-`const` version of the same member function is so you can call them on a `const` and non-`const` object:

```
Link link = ...;
link.find("hello"); // calls non-const find(), returns Link*

const Link clink = ...;
clink.find("goodbye"); // calls find() const
```

Although, your `const` version returns `Link* const`. That is a `const` pointer to `Link`. It would make more sense to return a `const Link*`, a pointer to `const Link`:

```
Link* find(const std::string& );
const Link* find(const std::string& ) const;
```

In this way, your `const` `Link` could still find entries - just not modify them. That would maintain `const`-ness. It makes sense to be able to look for things in a const collection as long as you don't modify them.

Comment: If you were to do this, you should also provide const overloads for next() and previous(), so your clients can have consistent behavior within your class (otherwise, you could modify the collection by calling find("...")->previous()->next()).

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell from those two function declarations, you don't need both. The `const` version of the function would actually cover all possible use cases even if the non-`const` version didn't exist.

In fact, the best declaration would probably be this:

```
Link* find(const string& s) const;
```

The first `const` in this line:

```
Link* const find(const string& s) const;
```

just means that the returned pointer cannot be assigned to point so something else; however, since the returned pointer would be either used directly or instantly assigned to some variable, that first `const` is unnecessary.

Perhaps what you're looking for is this setup:

```
Link* find(const string& s);
const Link* find(const string& s) const;
```

Putting `const` next to the base type (Link) instead of the asterisk (which means that it's a pointer), you are now providing a method that can either give a pointer to some Link that either does or doesn't allow you to modify that Link depending on whether the Link you're calling it on is `const` or not.

Comment: I think that the proper answer should be that the second declaration's const is at the wrong place.
Basically, it should return a pointer to a const Link, not a const pointer to a Link

Comment: @KABoissonneault, I agree. With `Link* const` you can still modify the pointed-to `Link`, which seems to defeat the purpose of having that function be `const`!

Answer (score 1):

> Can you tell me why we need two versions of find()

Yes. Consider this code:

```
const Link x{ "x" };
auto y = x.find("x");
// y will be a Link * const, meaning you cannot change the pointer 
// address (not interesting) but you can change the object at that address.
```

versus:

```
Link x{ "x" };
auto y = x.find("x");
// y will be a Link *, meaning you can change both the pointer address
// contained in y (not interesting) and the object at that address
```

The const version can be called on const instances (and const references and pointers to const instances). The non-const version will only be callable on non-const instances.

Either way, the signature of the const version is incorrect: you should return a pointer to a const value, not a const pointer to a non-const value.

That is, the function should be:

```
Link const * const find(const string& s) const;   
//   ^^^^^   ^^^^^
```

or

```
Link const * find(const string& s) const;   
//   ^^^^^
```

but not:

```
Link * const find(const string& s) const;   
//     ^^^^^
```